# How to use flex to resize items relatively?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In the script below I am simulating a stepper and I'm using `row` and `col.` It looks more or less good.

However, if the page is use on wide screens (eg. `lg` and `xl`) the space between the steps is too wide. In other words, the stepper takes the whole width of its container. I would like it to take 60%, 80% or whatever instead. I can use media breakpoints to control this.

I would like that on wider screens, the steps are positioned nearer to each other. Also, there is a problem with the line between steps 3 and 4 as it breaks before.

Would moving from `row` and `col` to `flex` solve my problem? And if yes, how should I do it? Or this there an other alternative?

Note: Displaying on smaller screens is not an issue because in this case I'm hiding the step text.

```css
.row.justify-content-center div:last-child > div > div {
    display: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 9px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}

.circle {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card cw-480">
    <div class="card-body">
 

   <div class="align-text-center">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col text-center">
          <div id="step-1" class="circle">
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Step 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <div id="step-2" class="circle">
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Step 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <div id="step-3" class="circle">
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Step 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <div id="step-4" class="circle">
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Longlonglongstep 4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <div id="step-5" class="circle">
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Step 5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <div id="step-6" class="circle">
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Step 6</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your secondary requirement, about text position. You already seem to have that happening.

Comment: @isherwood Yep the second requirement is then obsolete.

Comment: @isherwood There is also a problem with the line between steps 3 and 4 as it breaks before. How can I fix that?

Comment: When I do that, a line extends to the edge to the screen on the right.

Comment: I still don't know understand what you are trying to achieve, can you attach a screenshot or something?

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue can be resolved with a simple container element. Bootstrap's `container` class (as opposed to `container-fluid`) results in limited total widths.

You could also put the card in a centered column of varying widths.

```css
.row.justify-content-center div:last-child>div>div {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 9px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.circle {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="card cw-480">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="align-text-center">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col text-center">
            <div id="step-1" class="circle">
              <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            
            <p>Step 1</p>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col text-center">
            <div id="step-2" class="circle">
              <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            
            <p>Step 2</p>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col text-center">
            <div id="step-3" class="circle">
              <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            
            <p>Step 3</p>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col text-center">
            <div id="step-4" class="circle">
              <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            
            <p>Longlonglongstep 4</p>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col text-center">
            <div id="step-5" class="circle">
              <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            
            <p>Step 5</p>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col text-center">
            <div id="step-6" class="circle">
              <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            
            <p>Step 6</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the class for extra large screen and wrote a custom class for the large screen (copied from another stack overflow answer).

It also solves the problem with the line between steps 3 and 4

```
.col-lg-1-5 {
    flex: 0 0 12.3%;
    max-width: 12.3%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
  .row.justify-content-center div:last-child > div > div {
      display: none;
  }

  .line {
      width: 100%;
      height: 9px;
      margin-left: 16px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      pointer-events: none;
      cursor: default;
  }

  .circle {
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      background-color: lightgrey;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
  }

  .col-lg-1-5 {
      flex: 0 0 12.3%;
      max-width: 12.3%;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
  }
</style>

<div class="card cw-480">
    <div class="card-body"> 

   <div class="align-text-center">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col col-xl-1 col-lg-1-5 text-center">
          <div id="step-1" class="circle">
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Step 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-xl-1 col-lg-1-5 text-center">
          <div id="step-2" class="circle">
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Step 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-xl-1 col-lg-1-5 text-center">
          <div id="step-3" class="circle">
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Step 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-xl-1 col-lg-1-5 text-center">
          <div id="step-4" class="circle">
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Longlonglongstep 4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-xl-1 col-lg-1-5 text-center">
          <div id="step-5" class="circle">
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Step 5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-xl-1 col-lg-1-5 text-center">
          <div id="step-6" class="circle">
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Step 6</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```